# Mocking an Assert statement

Tags: python-3.x, mocking, assert

I am teaching an introductory python course (python 3+Jupyter), and have been formulating assignments using nbgrader. For those not familiar, this basically means marking student's code via a set of assert statements. If the assert doesn't pass, they don't get the mark.

One of the tests that I want to perform  is to check that students are writing their own tests. As a very simple example, let's imagine that they're supposed to be defining `my_function`, and all the tests that they want to run on it are supposed to be a series of `assert` statements inside a function `do_tests()` which will return True if all the tests pass.

One thing that I can obviously require of their code is that `do_tests()` passes simply by calling `assert do_tests()`. I can also check that it fails if I `del my_function`. However, I also want to check a bit more detail about the content of `do_tests()`. As a first step, I simply wanted to count the number of `assert` statements that they have used within the definition, and was intending to use `unittest.mock.patch`, trying to adapt the code from [here](https://nbgrader.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/autograding_resources.html#checking-how-functions-were-called-or-not-called-with-mocking). However, I could not figure out how to mock `assert`. I tried something like

```
from unittest.mock import patch
with patch('__main__.assert') as mock_assert:
    do_tests()
```

but I just get an error that main does not have a method assert, and couldn't work out what module assert should be a part of.

As a crude interim, I have ended up doing

```
import inspect
lines = inspect.getsource(do_tests)
assert lines.count("\n    assert")>=3,"You don't appear to have enough assert statements"
```

but obviously that doesn't give me access to any other features that mocking might offer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24478727/how-to-list-available-tests-with-python

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004455/how-can-i-extract-a-list-of-testcases-from-a-testsuite

Comment: [assert](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement) is a statement, not a `builtin`. I'm not sure mock has a way to patch them.

Comment: You could tell them to use one assert per test and count tests as mentioned above.